# How to install KIF 1.0.0 instead of KIF 2.0.0 for appthwack

Tags: ios7, xcode5, cocoapods, kif-framework, kif

I have sucessfully integrated KIF 2.0.0 in my Xcode workspace using cocoapods,and have created a number of test scripts as well.But for testing my iOS app in https://appthwack.com/, I need to switch back to the lower version of KIF,which is KIF 1.0.0.How can I do that,since I am not seeing the way to integrate KIF 1.0.0 now.Also do I need to change my associated test scripts for running in KIF 1.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

In your podfile:

```
pod 'KIF', '1.0.0'
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can run KIF 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0 on AppThwack, so there's no need to maintain multiple sets of tests or port back and forth.

For KIF 1.0, you must select KIF 1.0 when configuring your AppThwack test run.

For KIF 2.0, you must select OCUnit, as KIF 2.0 is built on top of OCUnit.

For KIF 3.0, you must select XCTest, as KIF 3.0 targets XCTest by default, unless you're explicitly targeting OCUnit, in which case you should follow the same steps as KIF 2.0.

I realize this is a little confusing, but KIF is a moving target. Cool framework, though.